# How to override "no non-const reference to temporary object" correctly

Tags: c++11, pass-by-rvalue-reference

I have a class `Foo`. `Foo` has a few non-const methods. I am okay with calling non-const methods on a temporary `Foo` object; I am only interested in what the methods actually return, than what they do to the `Foo` object itself.

First question: Does this, by itself, necessary indicate that the class `Foo` is not well-designed?

Second question: If I want to continue with `Foo` as-is, but I still want to be able to pass `Foo` objects by reference to functions that will call non-const methods on it, what would be the best way to do it?

This is what I arrived at:

```
// The function that performs work on a Foo object.
int TakeFoo (Foo& FooBar) { ... }

// An overload just to accept temporary Foo objects.
int TakeFoo (Foo&& FooBar)
{
    // Delegate
    return TakeFoo(FooBar);
}
```

The alternative approach is just doing this:

```
int TakeFoo (const Foo& FooBar)
{
    Foo& MyFooBar = const_cast<Foo&>(FooBar);
    // Do work on MyFooBar
}
```

But this approach has the problem that you may be const-cast'ing away the const on an object that was actually declared const, which would put me in undefined-behavior-land.

Edit:

Code examples that use TakeFoo:

```
Foo GimmeFoo() { ... }

cout << TakeFoo(GimmeFoo()) << endl;

Foo ConstructedFoo(...);

cout << TakeFoo(ConstructedFoo) << endl;

// Continue to use ConstructedFoo
```

Comment: can you also add some code to show how client code's going to call and use `TakeFoo`?

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your second question:

If your function TakeFoo is meant to call non const members of Foo then use

```
int TakeFoo (Foo& FooBar);
```

If you are sure that TakeFoo only takes an rvalue as argument then use

```
int TakeFoo (Foo&& FooBar);
```

If you want to do some changes to Foo in order to compute the `int` return value then use

```
int TakeFoo (const Foo& FooBar)
{
    Foo FooBar MyFooBar = FooBar;
    // do something with MyFooBar and return int
}
```

Or

```
int TakeFoo (Foo FooBar);
```

Answer to your first question:

`int TakeFoo (FooBar)` should not change FooBar in order to compute the `int` result.
A better design would be

```
Foo transform_foo(Foo const& foo);
int compute_result(Foo const& foo);
int TakeFoo(Foo const& FooBar)
{
    return compute_result( transform_foo(FooBar) );
}
```